# How does calling Snackbar.make() from non-UI thread work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, android-snackbar

I  can call `Snackbar.make()` from a background thread without any problems. This is surprising to me since I thought UI operations are only allowed from the UI thread. But that is definitely not the case here.

What exactly makes `Snackbar.make()` different? Why doesn't this cause exceptions like any other UI component when you modify it from a background thread?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all: `make()` doesn't perform any UI related operations, it just creates a new `Snackbar` instance. It is the call to `show()` which actually adds the `Snackbar` to the view hierarchy and performs other dangerous UI related tasks. However you can do that safely from any thread because it is implemented to schedule any show or hide operation on the UI thread regardless of which thread called `show()`.

For a more detailed answer let's take a closer look at the behaviour in the source code of the `Snackbar`:

---

Let's start where it all begins, with your call to `show()`:

```
public void show() {
    SnackbarManager.getInstance().show(mDuration, mManagerCallback);
}
```

As you can see the call to `show()` gets an instance of the `SnackbarManager` and then passes the duration and a callback to it. The `SnackbarManager` is a singleton. Its the class which takes care of displaying, scheduling and managing a `Snackbar`. Now lets continue with the implementation of `show()` on the `SnackbarManager`:

```
public void show(int duration, Callback callback) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (isCurrentSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            // Means that the callback is already in the queue. We'll just update the duration
            mCurrentSnackbar.duration = duration;

            // If this is the Snackbar currently being shown, call re-schedule it's
            // timeout
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mCurrentSnackbar);
            scheduleTimeoutLocked(mCurrentSnackbar);
            return;
        } else if (isNextSnackbarLocked(callback)) {
            // We'll just update the duration
            mNextSnackbar.duration = duration;
        } else {
            // Else, we need to create a new record and queue it
            mNextSnackbar = new SnackbarRecord(duration, callback);
        }

        if (mCurrentSnackbar != null && cancelSnackbarLocked(mCurrentSnackbar,
                Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_CONSECUTIVE)) {
            // If we currently have a Snackbar, try and cancel it and wait in line
            return;
        } else {
            // Clear out the current snackbar
            mCurrentSnackbar = null;
            // Otherwise, just show it now
            showNextSnackbarLocked();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this method call is a little more complicated. I am not going to explain in detail what's going on here, but in general the `synchronized` block around this ensures thread safety of calls to `show()`.

Inside the `synchronized` block the manager takes care of dismissing currently shown `Snackbars` updating durations or rescheduling if you `show()` the same one twice and of course creating new `Snackbars`. For each `Snackbar` a `SnackbarRecord` is created which contains the two parameters originally passed to the `SnackbarManager`, the duration and the callback:

```
mNextSnackbar = new SnackbarRecord(duration, callback);
```

In the above method call this happens in the middle, in the else statement of the first if.

However the only really important part - at least for this answer - is right down at the bottom, the call to `showNextSnackbarLocked()`. This where the magic happens and the next Snackbar is queued - at least sort of.

This is the source code of `showNextSnackbarLocked()`:

```
private void showNextSnackbarLocked() {
    if (mNextSnackbar != null) {
        mCurrentSnackbar = mNextSnackbar;
        mNextSnackbar = null;

        final Callback callback = mCurrentSnackbar.callback.get();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.show();
        } else {
            // The callback doesn't exist any more, clear out the Snackbar
            mCurrentSnackbar = null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see first we check if a Snackbar is queued by checking if `mNextSnackbar` is not null. If it isn't we set the `SnackbarRecord` as the current `Snackbar` and retrieve the callback from the record. Now something kind of round about happens, after a trivial null check to see if the callback is valid we call `show()` on the callback, which is implemented in the `Snackbar` class - not in the `SnackbarManager` - to actually show the `Snackbar` on the screen.

At first this might seem weird, however it makes a lot of sense. The `SnackbarManager` is just responsible for tracking the state of `Snackbars` and coordinating them, it doesn't care how a `Snackbar` looks, how it is displayed or what it even is, it just calls the `show()` method on the right callback at the right moment to tell the `Snackbar` to show itself.

---

Let's  rewind for a moment, up until now we never left the background thread. The `synchronized` block in the `show()` method of the `SnackbarManager` ensured that no other `Thread` can interfere with everything we did, but what schedules the show and dismiss events on the main `Thread` is still missing. That however is going to change right now when we look at the implementation of the callback in the `Snackbar` class:

```
private final SnackbarManager.Callback mManagerCallback = new SnackbarManager.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void show() {
        sHandler.sendMessage(sHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SHOW, Snackbar.this));
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss(int event) {
        sHandler.sendMessage(sHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_DISMISS, event, 0, Snackbar.this));
    }
};
```

So in the callback a message is send to a static handler, either `MSG_SHOW` to show the `Snackbar` or `MSG_DISMISS` to hide it again. The `Snackbar` itself is attached to the message as payload. Now we are almost done as soon as we look at the declaration of that static handler:

```
private static final Handler sHandler;
private static final int MSG_SHOW = 0;
private static final int MSG_DISMISS = 1;

static {
    sHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case MSG_SHOW:
                    ((Snackbar) message.obj).showView();
                    return true;
                case MSG_DISMISS:
                    ((Snackbar) message.obj).hideView(message.arg1);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

So this handler runs on the UI thread since it is created using the UI looper (as indicated by `Looper.getMainLooper()`). The payload of the message - the `Snackbar` - is casted and then depending on the type of the message either `showView()` or `hideView()` is called on the `Snackbar`. **Both of these methods are now executed on the UI thread!**

The implementation of both of these is kind of complicated, so I won't go into detail of what exactly happens in each of them. However it should be obvious that these methods take care of adding the `View` to the view hierarchy, animating it when it appears and disappears, dealing with `CoordinatorLayout.Behaviours` and other stuff regarding the UI.

If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

---

Scrolling through my answer I realize that this turned out **way** longer than it was supposed to be, however when I see source code like this I can't help myself! I hope you appreciate a long in depth answer, or maybe I might have just wasted a few minutes of my time!

Comment: No, you didn't waste your time, much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

`Snackbar.make` is completely safe from being called form non-ui thread. It uses an handler inside its manager which operates on the main looper thread and thus hides the caller form the underlying complexities of it.

Comment: The `Handler` in the manager plays no part in this. It is just uses for notifying `SnackbarRecords` of timeouts. There is a separate `Handler` in the `Snackbar` class which actually takes care of showing or hiding the `Snackbar`.

Comment: that still doesn't amount to 2 down votes. Snackbar is completely safe form being called from any thread. The point is that it uses a handler on the main looper to do its work. That is what the original question owner needs to understand. I cant dismiss these down votes so am not goign to fight them either. Th

Answer (score -2):

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

If you use the onPostExecute you'll be able to access the views

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object object) { .. }
```